# How do I create a .wsgi file?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, flask

I am completely confused.   I am trying to get Flask to work with mod_wsgi.   I have a script alias that is supposed to point to myapp.wsgi.  I cannot make a .wsgi file in python, because he would be .py.   I cannot make a text file .wsgi because it is a .wsgi.txt file.

Is there a software application that I need to use to actually create a .wsgi file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the View tab, and then, under Advanced settings, to display file extensions, clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK. That will show you extensions for all file, and after saving .wsgi text file you could just delete .txt extension.

Was that your problem?

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Show-or-hide-file-name-extensions

Answer (score 1):

You wrote, "I cannot make a .wsgi file in python, because he would be .py.", but that's not really true. Both file extensions are for text files, and you can fill them with whatever text you want. In this case, if you follow [the instructions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/) for making the .wsgi file, you should be fine.